# Many addCase when using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a react app that on initial load does a lot of fetch calls to retrieve some data.

I'm using redux with redux toolkit to manage state

As you can see, in my redux slice, there are a lot of chained addCase calls that simply handles setting loading states for my fetches to `loading` or `failed`

Is there a way to avoid this and make my code more concise? A way to make a single addCase that handles setting the loading state to `loading` for all fetches and equally for `failed`?

```
export const dashboardSlice = createSlice({
  name: "dashboard",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      //Co2Emission
      .addCase(fetchCO2EmissionData.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.co2.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchCO2EmissionData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.co2.status = "succeeded";
        //We are just using the CPU data from first pod in the array. When when KG-121 it should just be state.Co2DiagramData = action.payload.values
        console.log(action.payload[0]);
        const transformedData = action.payload[0].values.map(d=>({Date: convertDate(d[0]*1000),"Grams of CO2": parseFloat(d[1])}));
        state.co2.data = transformedData;
      })
      .addCase(fetchCO2EmissionData.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.co2.status = "failed";
      })
      //Active pods
      .addCase(fetchActivePods.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.pods.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchActivePods.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.pods.status = "succeeded";
        state.pods.currentValue = parseFloat(action.payload[0].values.pop().pop());
        state.pods.data = action.payload[0].values;
      })
      .addCase(fetchActivePods.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.pods.status = "failed";
      })
      //Cpu usage
      .addCase(fetchCpuUsage.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusUsage = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchCpuUsage.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusUsage = 'succeeded';
        state.cpu.currentUsage = parseFloat(action.payload[0].values.pop().pop());
        state.cpu.usage = action.payload[0].values;
      })
      .addCase(fetchCpuUsage.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusUsage = 'failed'
      })
      //cpu allocation
      .addCase(fetchCpuAllocation.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusAllocation = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchCpuAllocation.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusAllocation = 'succeeded';
        if(action.payload.values.length !== 0){
          state.cpu.currentAllocated = parseFloat(action.payload[0].values.pop().pop());
          state.cpu.allocated = action.payload[0].values;
        }
      })
      .addCase(fetchCpuAllocation.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusAllocation = 'failed'
      })
      //memory usage
      .addCase(fetchMemoryUsage.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.memory.statusUsage = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchMemoryUsage.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.memory.statusUsage = 'succeeded';
        state.memory.currentUsage = parseFloat(action.payload[0].values.pop().pop());
        state.memory.usage = action.payload[0].values;
      })
      .addCase(fetchMemoryUsage.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.memory.statusUsage = 'failed'
      })
      //memory allocation
      .addCase(fetchMemoryAllocation.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.cpu.statusAllocation = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(fetchMemoryAllocation.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.memory.statusAllocation = 'succeeded';
        if(action.payload[0].values.length !== 0){
          state.memory.currentAllocated = parseFloat(action.payload[0].values.pop().pop());
          state.memory.allocated = action.payload[0].values;
        }
      })
      .addCase(fetchMemoryAllocation.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.memory.statusAllocation = 'failed'
      })
  }
})

export default dashboardSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably take a look at RTK Query, which is also a part of Redux Toolkit and handles all this stuff internally - you just describe your API and it generates the reducer, middleware and even hooks for you automatically. No need to handle loading states by hand.

It is covered [here in the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)